# In Pandas can we select columns by names and by regex?

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say my Pandas data frame was as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    dict(ID = [1, 2, 3],
         xz = [0, 1, 1],
         yz = [4, 5, 6],
         yx = [7, 11, 18],
         xy = [10, 10, 11])
)
```

If I want to select all those columns whose names contain an `x`, I could do the following:

```
df.filter(regex = 'x', axis=1)
```

If I also want to select by column names, I would like to do the following, which will not work.

```
df.filter(items = ['ID'], regex = 'x', axis=1)
```

It won't work because

```
TypeError: Keyword arguments `items`, `like`, or `regex` are mutually exclusive`
```

Here's an alternative that does work.

```
df.iloc[:,df.columns.str.contains('x') | 
          df.columns.str.match('ID')]
```

Is there a better or more recommended way?

I am aware how painlessly this can be done using R/tidyverse, i.e. `Df %>% select(ID, contains('x'))`. I am also aware of `siuba` and `dplython` etc that implement much of `dplyr`'s functionality with Pandas. What I am asking here is about the recommended "base Pandas" way of doing this?

Answer (score 5):

You can match on both conditions separating with a `|`, which acts like an `or` for pattern matching. If you want to match exact column names, you'll need to add the beginning and end of strings too:

```
df.filter(regex = r'x|^ID$', axis=1)

   ID  xz  yx  xy
0   1   0   7  10
1   2   1  11  10
2   3   1  18  11
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/tExXz3/1)

---

Note however that you're approach using `str.contains` and `str.contains` is perfectly fine. This is just a more concise approach, but not necessarily better.

Comment: Thanks. I see that my original regular expression for matching 'x' was unnecessary as so changed it in the original post, though my question is the same.